# Poisson random variable: exchanging expectation operator with exponential operator?

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

**EDITED THANKS TO THE COMMENTS BELOW**

Consider a random variable $C$ distributed as a Poisson with rate $\lambda$ (see formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)). Further, assume that the rate $\lambda$ is distributed as a Gamma with mean $1$ and variance $\phi$.

First, note that the probability that $C$ is at least equal to $1$ conditional on $\lambda$ is
$$
P(C\geq 1|\lambda)=1-P(C=0|\lambda)=1-\exp(-\lambda)
$$

Second, note that the unconditional probability that $C\geq 1$ is (**thanks to the comments below**)
$$
P(C\geq 1)=1-\int_{t} \exp(-t) f(t) dt
$$
where $f$ is the Gamma distribution with mean $1$ and variance $\phi$.

Third, I believe that for any $c\geq 1$
$$
P(C\geq 1| \lambda, C=c)=P(C\geq 1| C=c)=1
$$
while 
$$
P(C\geq 1| \lambda, C=0)=P(C\geq 1| C=0)=0
$$

---

**Question**: 
a book that I'm using considers the following objects
$$
(A)\text{ }1-\exp(-E(\lambda))
$$
and
$$
(B)\text{ }1-\exp(-E(\lambda| C))
$$
where $E$ denotes the expectation. In particular, B is referred to as Bayesian Credibility Premium.

What do A and B represent? What is the relation between A and B and the objects derived above? How do I compute $E(\lambda|C=c)$ for any $c$ given only the information above?

Comment: How do you get your equation $P[C=1|\lambda] = \lambda \exp(-\lambda)$? More importantly, *why* are you writing an equation for event $\{C=1\}$ when you care about the event $\{C\geq 1\}$?

Comment: Note that $P(C\ge1)=1-P(C=0)$.

Comment: Again, *why* are you looking at $C=1$ when you care about $C\geq 1$?

Comment: But you compute the unconditional $P[C=1]$ by the law of total probability.  Why not compute the unconditional $P[C\geq 1]$ by the (same) law of total probability?